# NLog:: adding source code line number to the log

Tags: nlog

I need source code line number to the log entry through NLog.

Please let me know alternate ways to do it.

```
<<Log entry>> Line 23 
 <<Log entry>> Line 391
```

P.S. - 23, 391 are the source code line numbers.
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You may use ${callsite:fileName=true} layout renderer - indicates whether to render the source file name and line number. [Documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer).

Comment: thanks a lot ppl. it did not work out exactly because I was calling a Log() in a helper class. using callsite gave me file informatin from the callsite class. So i finally used StackFrame and got the line number and the file being used for the same.

Comment: @CuriousBenjamin When wrapping NLog with custom helper-classes, then one just need to tell NLog. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412156/how-to-retain-callsite-information-when-wrapping-nlog

Answer (score -2):

Not sure but you should try this. Hope it will help :D

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/filename-and-line-number-with-nslog-part-ii.html

and I also found this

```
NSLog(@"current line: %d",__LINE__);
```

from this 
[How can I log the current line via NSLog in Cocoa / Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547152/how-can-i-log-the-current-line-via-nslog-in-cocoa-objective-c)

EDIT sry I dont know that u want C#
should try look at this

[Do __LINE__ __FILE__ equivalents exist in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696218/do-line-file-equivalents-exist-in-c)

Comment: can someone tell me c# way to do it?